# SEHException while running azure project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have just moved my azure project from sdk version 1.4 to 2.1.

After this move, I am having trouble starting the azure roles on my local machine. I get the following error:

```
[SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception.]
   RdGetApplicationConfigurationSetting(UInt16* , UInt16** ) +0
   RoleEnvironmentGetConfigurationSettingValueW(UInt16* pszName, UInt16* pszDest, UInt32 cchDest, UInt32* pcchRequiredDestSize) +82
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Internal.InteropRoleManager.GetConfigurationSetting(String name, String& ret) +232
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(String configurationSettingName) +67
   Surfmark.MVC.WebRole.FirstRequestInitialization.ApplicationStartUponFirstRequest(HttpContext context) in C:\Dev\code\www\Surfmark.CloudService\Surfmark.MVC.WebRole\Global.asax.cs:232
   Surfmark.MVC.WebRole.FirstRequestInitialization.Initialize(HttpContext context) in C:\Dev\code\www\Surfmark.CloudService\Surfmark.MVC.WebRole\Global.asax.cs:223
   Surfmark.MVC.WebRole.MvcApplication.Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Dev\code\www\Surfmark.CloudService\Surfmark.MVC.WebRole\Global.asax.cs:202
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +148
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

Please note that I am making a call to RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue() in the Application_BeginRequest() method in Global.asax. While using v1.4 of Azure SDK, I used to call CloudStorageAccount.SetConfigurationSettingPublisher() in the Application_Start() so that getting the configsetting doesnt error out. I notice that in v2.1 this method is no more there, so I am assuming I can access RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue() without error.

Please let me know what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks
Kapil

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out. Actually I was upgrading my proj from 1.4 to 2.1 version od azure SDK. Now, I noticed that my proj was using full IIS to start the compute emulator on dev machine. I moved that to IIS-express (seems like thats the default for dev emulator in the new SDKs) and things seem to work well.

Thanks
Kapil